# Django Image Field not Updating on the Front

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying to get my app to validate the image upload field in my app's template and save any new image that is uploaded. Everything works fine on the admin side of things but when I make an image change on the front, it doesn't get saved.

Here is my model

```
def imageupload(instance, filename):
    return os.path.join('static/petition-photos/', filename)

# Create your models here.

class Petition(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length= 90, default="Enter petition title here")
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    image = models.ImageField(null=False, upload_to=imageupload)
    video = models.CharField(max_length=600, default="Enter an external video link")
    petition = models.TextField(null=False, default="Type your petition here")
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Here is my view class:

```
class NewPetitionView(generic.edit.CreateView):
model = Petition
template_name = 'petition/petition_form.html'
fields= ['title','petition', 'image', 'video']
success_url = '/dashboard/'

def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.created_by = self.request.user
    return super(NewPetitionView, self).form_valid(form)
```

And this is my form template:

```
{% include 'layout/header.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <form action="" method="post">
        {{form.as_p}}
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        {% csrf_token %} 
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

When I upload an image to a new post or try to edit the image field of one of the posted items, I get a "This field is required" notification.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need in your `<form>` add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in order to let file upload work.

`<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

[django doc.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/file-uploads/#basic-file-uploads)